# Qml ComboBox with TextField in Popup

Tags: qt, combobox, popup, qml, qcombobox

I have created a custom `ComboBox` that uses a `ListView` with a `TextField` in the footer, that's used to dynamically add options to the `ComboBox`.
The problem is, that as soon as the popup loses focus (so when the `TextField` receives focus), the popup gets closed.
I tried to force the popup to stay open, which does work, but then prevents the `TextField` from receiving focus (I guess because the popup regains focus as soon as `open()` is called).

```
ComboBox {
  // ...
  popup: Popup {
    property bool forceOpen: false
    onClosed: {
      if(forceOpen)
        open()
    }

    contentItem: ListView {
      // ...
      footer: TextField {
        onPressed: forceOpen = true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried all values for the `closePolicy` property of the `Popup`, but none of them helped.

I am using **Qt5.11**. The `forceOpen` solution used to work with Qt 5.10, but does not anymore.

Comment: This might be a bit of a weird question but why not to use `ComboBox` instead of creating the custom one?

Comment: Of, ofcourse I am using a regular ComboBox, I edited the entry post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem should be fixed if you do not accept the focus on the `ComboBox`:

```
ComboBox {
  focusPolicy: Qt.NoFocus
  popup: Popup {
    // ... 
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that really solved the problem. And it doesn't even require the messy workaround with a `forceOpen` property. Thanks!